Confirmation Email adding in extra line breaks
All of our confirmation emails for events are adding extra line breaks. For instance, if we do:
Monday
8-10 a.m.: Morning Online Event
Between online events: Exercises, reading & break

there will be an extra line added between every line, so it looks like this:
Monday
8-10 a.m.: Morning Online Event
Between online events: Exercises, reading & break
Screenshots:
I've included a screenshot of the email as setup in CiviCRM and how it looks when you receive the email. I can go into the source and run all of the code together as an unbroken line, which works until you edit the page again. Then, it resets to how it was.
We're running CiviCRM 5.79.0 on Drupal 7.
SCREENSHOTS: CONFIRMATION EMAIL IN EVENT SETUP


SCREENSHOTS: ACTUAL EMAIL



